# Ignore first 2 characters of string in where query using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How Can I find all records that match my string, ignoring exactly two characters from the start of the fields string.

Something Like:

```
Things.where("reference like ?", "**#{MyReference}")
```

Where ** can be any two characters, but not none, one or three or more characters

Comment: The underscore ```_``` is the PostgreSQL wildcard for exactly one character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use underscore(_) to match the pattern - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-matching.html

You can also use ~~ instead of like. So the query will be like -
Things.where("reference ~~ ?", "__#{MyReference}")